# Image Compression using Quadtrees Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression, quadtree

So I'm basically trying to implement a basic image compression algorithm using quadtrees in java; however, I'm really stuck on how to turn anything more than four pixels into a quadtree.  My gut feeling is recursion.

Basically right now, this is my idea. This obviously only works for an image with 4 pixels. I'm not should how I would dig deeper into the image array.

```
if(sideLength == 2){
        QuadNode parent = new QuadNode(image.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < image.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < image[0].length; j++){
                QuadNode child = new QuadNode(image[i][j], image.length/2);
                if (j == 0 && i == 0) 
                    parent.setQuadrant(UpperLeft, child);
                if (j == 0 && i == 1) 
                    parent.setQuadrant(LowerLeft, child);
                if (j == 1 && i == 0)
                    parent.setQuadrant(UpperRight, child);
                if (j == 1 && i == 1)
                    parent.setQuadrant(LowerRight, child);
            }
        }   
        return new QuadTree(parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There can be many ways to compress image. The below is an algorithm using quadtrees.

The idea is to minimize the number of quadtree nodes used in the tree when you are recursively dividing the image. We stop dividing the a particular node if all the pixels in that rectangle contain same color.

An example Node structure looks like this.

```
class QuadTreeNode
{
    Point topLeft;
    int width;
    int height;
    QuadTreeNode children[4];
    int color;
};
```

If you go by dividing the image at center you will not achieve optimum compression.

Now the main task is to find out the (i,j) where we should divide. For this dynamic programming and hashing comes in handy.

```
class HashValue
{
    Point p; // location to cut into quads
    int count;// To contain number of Quadtree Nodes;
};

HashMap<Rect,HashValue> H; 
int createQuadTree(Rect rect)
{
    if(Hash.find(rect)!= Hash.end()) return Hash[rect];

    if(isMonoChromatic(rect))// If all the pixels are of same color we stop dividing.
    {
        Hash[rect] = {NULL,1};
        return 1;
    }

    int x=rect.x,y=rect.y,w =rect.w,h=rect.h;
    int minCount;
    Point minCut;
    for(i=x;i<x+w;i++)
    {
        for(j=y;j<x+h;j++)
        {
            int val = 1;
            val= val+ createQuadTree(Rect(x,y,i,j));
            val= val+ createQuadTree(Rect(x,j,w-i,j));
            val= val+ createQuadTree(Rect(i,y,i,h-j));
            val= val+ createQuadTree(Rect(i,j,w-i,h-j));
            if(val < minCount)
            {
                minCount = val;
                minCutPoint = {i,j};
            }
        }
     }
     Hash[rect] = {minCutPoint,minCount};
     return val;
}
```

Using this HashTable it is straight forward to build the QuadTree.  It is complex algo with O(M, N) recursive steps with each step O(M,N) adds to O(M^2,N^2). You can decrease the complexity of isMonoChromatic function by doing some preprocessing on the image.

P.S. Sorry for the long post. I hope it helps.